# OSX - #include "portaudio.h" 1 error generated. error: command '/usr/bin/clang' failed with exit status 1

Tags: python, macos, terminal, pyaudio

I am busy with making a speech recognition code and I have this:

```
from pocketsphinx.pocketsphinx import *
from sphinxbase.sphinxbase import *

import os
import pyaudio
import wave
import audioop
from collections import deque
import time
import math

 class SpeechDetector:
     def __init__(self):
        self.CHUNK = 1024
        self.FORMAT = pyaudio.paInt16
        self.CHANNELS = 1
        self.RATE = 16000

        self.SILENCE_LIMIT = 1
        self.PREV_AUDIO = 0.5

        self.THRESHOLD = 4500
        self.num_phrases = -1

        MODELDIR = "../../tools/pocketsphinx/model"
        DATADIR = "../../tools/pocketsphinx/test/data"

        config = Decoder.default_config()
        config.set_string('-hmm', os.path.join(MODELDIR, 'en-us/en-us'))
        config.set_string('-lm', os.path.join(MODELDIR, 'en-us/en-us.lm.bin'))
        config.set_string('-dict', os.path.join(MODELDIR, 'en-us/cmudict-en-us.dict'))

        self.decoder = Decoder(config)

    def setup_mic(self, num_samples=50):
        print "Getting intensity values from mic."
        p = pyaudio.PyAudio()
        stream = p.open(format=self.FORMAT,
                        channels=self.CHANNELS,
                        rate=self.RATE,
                        input=True,
                        frames_per_buffer=self.CHUNK)

        values = [math.sqrt(abs(audioop.avg(stream.read(self.CHUNK), 4)))
            for x in range(num_samples)]
            values = sorted(values, reverse=True)
        r = sum(values[:int(num_samples * 0.2)]) / int(num_samples * 0.2)
        print " Finished "
        print " Average audio intensity is ", r
        stream.close()
        p.terminate()

        if r < 3000:
            self.THRESHOLD = 3500
        else:
            self.THRESHOLD = r + 100

    def save_speech(self, data, p):

        filename = 'output_'+str(int(time.time()))
        data = ''.join(data)
        wf = wave.open(filename + '.wav', 'wb')
        wf.setnchannels(1)
        wf.setsampwidth(p.get_sample_size(pyaudio.paInt16))
        wf.setframerate(16000)
        wf.writeframes(data)
        wf.close()
        return filename + '.wav'

def decode_phrase(self, wav_file):
    self.decoder.start_utt()
    stream = open(wav_file, "rb")
    while True:
        buf = stream.read(1024)
        if buf:
            self.decoder.process_raw(buf, False, False)
            self.decoder.end_utt()

            words = []
            [words.append(seg.word) for seg in self.decoder.seg()]
            return words

def run(self):
    self.setup_mic()

p = pyaudio.PyAudio()
stream = p.open(format=self.FORMAT,
                channels=self.CHANNELS,
                rate=self.RATE,
                input=True,
                frames_per_buffer=self.CHUNK)
print "* Mic set up and listening. "

audio2send = []
cur_data = ''
rel = self.RATE/self.CHUNK
slid_win = deque(maxlen=self.SILENCE_LIMIT * rel)
prev_audio = deque(maxlen=self.PREV_AUDIO * rel)
started = False

while True:
    cur_data = stream.read(self.CHUNK)
    slid_win.append(math.sqrt(abs(audioop.avg(cur_data, 4))))

    if sum([x > self.THRESHOLD for x in slid_win]) > 0:
        if started == False:
            print "Starting recording of phrase"
            started = True
            audio2send.append(cur_data)
       elif started:
           print "Finished recording, decoding phrase"
           filename = self.save_speech(list(prev_audio) + audio2send, p)
            r = self.decode_phrase(filename)
            print "DETECTED: ", r
            os.remove(filename)

stream.close()
p.terminate()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    sd = SpeechDetector()
    sd.run()
```

but every time I run it it says: ImportError: No module named pyaudio.

Then I go to terminal and I do pip install pyaudio
but then it shows this:

```
#include "portaudio.h"

         ^
1 error generated.
error: command '/usr/bin/clang' failed with exit status 1
```

I'm using a Macbook with MacOS Sierra version 10.12.5 from 2011. I looked at every stack overflow page but nothing worked with me. Please help me!

Comment: are you in a virtualenv? If not, did you tried with sudo ?

Comment: I tried brew install but it said something like: bash: command "brew" not known and I tried pip install but that showed the comment above

Comment: Ok, so let add `osx` tag to your question, by default lot of users think about linux.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need portaudio installed before installing pyaudio. Install portaudio with homebrew

From [pyaudio](https://people.csail.mit.edu/hubert/pyaudio/) website

> Apple Mac OS X
>       Use Homebrew to install the prerequisite portaudio library, then install PyAudio using pip:
>
> ```
> brew install portaudio 
> pip install pyaudio
> ```
>
> Notes:
>
> If not already installed, download Homebrew.
>       pip will download the PyAudio source and build it for your version of Python.
>       Homebrew and building PyAudio also require installing the Command Line Tools for Xcode (more information).

Comment: and if I do import PyAudio it says:                                                                        
AttributeError: Could not find PyAudio; check installation

Comment: I installed Homebrew via Pip but it did not install PyAudio and I also installed the command line tools for xcode

Comment: you need to install pyaudio via pip and portaudio via homebrew to get it working.  run `pip install pyaudio` and check what is the output. You can also find pyaudio is installed by running `pip show pyaudio`. If you are running your application inside a virtual environment, make sure you do pip install inside the virtual env.

Comment: Via Pip it says the error above, if I do brew install it says: -bash: brew: commando not found and if I do Pip show pyaudio it shows nothing

Comment: You need to install brew first, brew is not a standard tool that comes pre installed with Mac osx. Once you install brew, install portaudio with brew and then pyaudio via pip.

Comment: when I do pip install brew it says: Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /private/var/folders/t7/j_5ng20x4sgb2zgk16bnzqsc0000gn/T/pip-build-JLmv30/brew/

Comment: Thank you so much for helping me, I did not know how to install brew but now I installed it. I installed pyaudio via brew and it worked like a charm! Thank you for helping me!!!

Answer (score 1):

In my case, installing `pyaudio` still failed after `brew install portaudio`.

I deleted my python env(which created by virtualenv), and it works.

Comment: did you get any solution?